# baseline align in React native

Tags: css, react-native

[image]

```
 <View style={ViewStyle}>
   <Text
     includeFontPadding={false}
     textAlignVertical='bottom'
     style={Text1Style}
   >
     hello
   </Text>
   <Text
     includeFontPadding={false}
     textAlignVertical='bottom'
     style={Text2Style}
   >
     world
   </Text>
 </View>

 const ViewStyle = {
   flexDirection: 'row',
   alignItems: 'baseline',
 }

 const Text1Style = {
   fontSize: 20,
 }

 const Text2Style = {
   fontSize: 10,
 }
```

How can I make them align at the baseline?

Comment: maybe remove `textAlignVertical='bottom'`

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround**

The workaround for this seems to be wrapping the `<Text>` elements in another `<Text>`, so you would use this structure:

```
 <Text>
   <Text>hello</Text>
   <Text>world</Text>
 </Text>
```

instead of:

```
 <View>
   <Text>hello</Text>
   <Text>world</Text>
 </View>
```

Keeping `alignItems='baseline'` on the outer element.

This however has the unfortunate side effect, that the nested Texts [cannot be positioned using Flexbox anymore](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#containers).

**Background: Issues filed against React Native**:

This seems to be a bug that affects android only. There are at least 4 issues filed against react-native for this. All of them seem to have been closed by bots or by humans without giving a specific reason or a solution that is not a workaround:

- [Some issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27137)
- [another one](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21918)
- [The one with the workaround above](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20666)
- [The first issue on this opened in 2017](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15858)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem originates from somewhere else. As i checked out your snippet for me it aligned at the baseline. Maybe the flexbox causes your problem.

Comment: Please do not post a link. An url is optional but you should insert the relevant code directly here.

Comment: Yeah I tried it on web simulator and it worked.. but not on actual android device..

Answer (score 0):

I've used your code  , and it aligned in baseline way. There must be a view or something wrapped which is causing the problem.  PFB . the link [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/HkoE7rVYS)

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Text
      paddingBottom={15}
      title=‘Hello’ />

     <Text title=‘World’ />
</View>
```

`alignItems` with `baseline` and different sized text didn't work for me as a work around the above piece of code was helpful.